# Kotlin -Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() Not Firing

Tags: android, kotlin, scheduled-tasks

I'm coming from an iOS background and currently learning Android.

I have the following code and I notice `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule` doesn't fire. I would like to know why.

```
interface MyScheduler {

    fun simulateNetworkCall(delay: Long, completion: () -> Unit) {
        
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule({
            completion()
        }, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyScheduler {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        turnButtonGray(true)

        simulateNetworkCall(5) {
            turnButtonGray(false) // this never occurs
        }
    }

    fun turnButtonGray(value: Boolean) {
        // toggle button background color to either gray(true) or green(false)
        binding.nextButton.setBackgroundResource(whichever color)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're facing is related to executing the completion() callback on the worker thread.

The `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule()` method schedules a task to be executed by a single-threaded executor service. In your case, the task is the lambda expression containing the completion() callback. This task is executed on the worker thread managed by the executor service.

Since you're updating the UI in the completion() callback by calling `turnButtonGray(false)`, you need to ensure that this UI-related code is executed on the main/UI thread.

To switch to the main/UI thread from the worker thread, you can use the `runOnUiThread()` method, which is available in the Activity class. Modify your code as follows:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyScheduler {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        turnButtonGray(true)

        simulateNetworkCall(5) {
            runOnUiThread {
                turnButtonGray(false)
            }
        }
    }

    // Rest of your code...
}
```

By wrapping the UI-related code within runOnUiThread { }, you ensure that it will be executed on the main/UI thread, allowing the button background color to be updated as expected.

Hope this helps!